# labels for dynamic textbox in php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to give label for dynamically created text box. How to do that?

**JavaScript**

```
$function add() {
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    $var element = document.createElement("input");

    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("name", "speaker[]");
    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code tidily

Comment: I'm confused, why does your title state PHP but this is JS?

Comment: If you use JS you should remove the $ character before function and var, looks like you tried to mix Javascript and PHP or JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Add one text node in the span :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'> 
            function addThings()
            {
                var label = document.createElement("div");
                label.innerHTML = "label"; // you can set class name or style to align the DIV

                var element = document.createElement("input");
                element.setAttribute("type", "text");
                element.setAttribute("name", "speaker[]");

                var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
                //Append the element in page (in span).
                foo.appendChild(label);
                foo.appendChild(element);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fooBar"></div>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" id="myButton" onclick='addThings()'>Add Label and Text</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am using this add function .... for one text field ...now i want o have place holders for the text boxes created dynamically

Comment: That was not tested. my bad. let me come back to you on this

Answer (score 0):

you just need to append an element like this using jquery

```
$(function(){
  $('.clickclass').click(function(){
     $('.classofspan').append("<lable>lable of text filed</lable>\
      <input type='text' name='anything[]' >");
 });
});
```

then if you want to add this add on a click event you can do this

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="clickclass">Add Field</a>
```

you can also perform action by adding a class to your action

```
<span class="classofspan"></span>
```

it will add input field in span whenever you press the link Add Filed

Comment: hey user 972 its working but that label is not coming to every textbox

Comment: gautham use this code i provided and also include jquery in your code to work this code

Comment: session.musurvey.in/session.php click on this the speaker name not comming exactly

Comment: yeah, you can put anything you want into it. Put details in the question instead of typing so many comments. It will help understanding the question more clearly. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: And the answer is exactly what you have asked for